# Does Elastic Search Support ACID properties

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, acid

Elastic search is referred to as text based search engine which persists data as json documents in index specified inside nodes which are a part of elastic search cluster.
Elastic Search is often referred as No-Sql Database also, so I was wondering whether it supports ACID properties(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) like some other No-Sql DB's. While going through it's documentation I saw it exposes asynchronous behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

### Elasticsearch is not ACID compliant Datastore.

It uses a search engine technology called Lucene. Lucene is an information retrieval technology built for speed, not redundancy. It has a radically different architecture that gives it blazing fast performance, at the expense of being more susceptible to data loss. So to overcome the dataloss you need a ACID compliant backup datastore.